# Azure CLI 2.0 Connection Error

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-cli, azure-files

Platform: MacOS Sierra
Version: Azure CLI 2.0
Mode: ARM

I'm trying to access file storage with below command:

```
az storage file list --share-name $SHARE_NAME --account-name $ACCT_NAME --account-key $ACCT_KEY
```

But I always get `ConnectionError`. I also tried other file storage command, same error all the time. Tried to search online, didn't find anything.

Can anyone help?

---

### Edit

Answers to those who asked for the "full message" of the error. "ConnectionError" is ALL the error message the Azure CLI gave me. nothing more.

Comment: Could you paste the full error message and console output in the question?

Comment: To troubleshoot this issue more efficiently, please post your error message here.

Comment: @ChrisPietschmann "ConnectionError" is the only output, it's the full error message.

Comment: @JasonYe-MSFT "ConnectionError" is the only output, it's the full error message.

Comment: What [detail version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/release-notes-azure-cli) of Azure cli, is there any proxy or VPN connection on your machine? Does any other commands work excluded the storage command? As [Azure cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli) is the cross-platform tool,  I test  the command  on windows platform that It works correctly on my side.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the command with the --debug flag to get additional diagnostics information. Furthermore, you can add an issue at [https://github.com/azure-azure-cli/issues](https://github.com/azure/azure-cli/issues) to see if the product team/contributors can further help out...

Please note that some of the information displayed in the --debug trace output contains secrets (in your case, the account key), so don't blindly include it in a post on a public forum (i.e. stackoverflow or in the github issue)